# Java generics: getting a subclass of Exception

Tags: java, generics, exception, subclass

ive been learning java recently and got to generics and exceptions
i have multiple classes that extend Exception as i need a bunch of custom exception in my project
for example the FileEmptyException:

and i also have an ExceptionHandler class

```
public class FileEmptyException extends Exception {


public FileEmptyException() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```

}

```
 public class ExceptionHandler<Ex extends Exception> {



List<Ex> ls;



public ExceptionHandler()
{
    
    ls = new ArrayList<>();
}
public void addException(Ex ex)
{
    ls.add(ex);
}
```

}

when i try to make an instance of my ExceptionHandler object and add the custom exception to the list, i encounter the compilation error "The method addException(capture#1-of ? extends Exception) in the type ExceptionHandler<capture#1-of ? extends Exception> is not applicable for the arguments (FileNotFoundException)"

i instantiated the object the following way:

```
private ExceptionHandler<? extends Exception> EH = new ExceptionHandler<>();
```

and called the function the following way:

```
        if(!s.hasNext())
        EH.addException(new FileEmptyException());
```

my main question is if what im trying to do is even possible(i assume yes) and if so what would be the correct way?

thanks in advance and sorry for my own ignorance!

Comment: See this answer on [the use of `super` instead of `extends`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4343547/636009).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way of expressing what you actually want to express in this case is to write `ExceptionHandler<Exception>`, not `ExceptionHandler<? extends Exception>`.

You may conclude from this that `ExceptionHandler` *shouldn't* be generic, and should just have a `List<Exception>`.  That's up to your use case.

Comment: if i use a non generic class at all it still wont compile
for some reason it doesnt recognize my exceptions as subclasses of Exception
ill try some stuff and report back!